# Add App Group entitlement

Tags: ios, ios8-today-widget, today-extension

I'm trying to build an existing application that provides a Today widget. Unfortunately I cannot make the app to communicate with the widget. In the Capabilities section I get the following errors

[image]

I've installed appropriate provisioning profiles and I've double-checked that the App ID in DevCenter includes App Groups. `Fix Issues` button throws an error as I don't have sufficient privileges in the team. What else should I try?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to have at least one device in your developer account at the DevCenter.
Hope it helped.